# Get the last ID of recently created database row

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to pull the last inserted id from a database table so that I can input it into a new database table, like so:

```
$mealplaninput =
    MealPlanInput::create([
          'meal_type' => $meal,
          'suitable_for' => $suited,
          'allergens' => $allerg,
          'specific_allergen' => $spec,
          'no_of_people' => $nop,
          'start_date' => $request->date,
          'no_of_days' => $nod,
          'user_id' => $currentuserid,
      ]);
```

The attempt to pull the last id (but doesn't work):

```
$uniquemealplanid = $mealplaninput->id();
```

To then input into new table:

```
MealPlanDisplay::create([
      'MealPlan_ID' => $uniquemealplanid,
      'Day' =>  $recipeday,
]);
```

However I get the error:

**Call to undefined method App\Models\MealPlanInput::id()**

I have tried other methods too, like:

```
$uniquemealplanid =  $this->create($mealplaninput)->id;
```

But the error I get is:

**Method App\Http\Controllers\MealPlanInputController::create does not exist.**

How can I pull the last id from MealPlanInput?

Comment: Isn't the `id` a property? Try just `$mealplaninput->id` instead of `$mealplaninput->id()`.

Comment: I tried it, and not sure why but it just returns null unfortunately.

Comment: Do a `dd($mealplaninput);` and check what it actually contains. As far as I know, it should return the new model with the id populated. Is your table's primary key `id`, or have you called it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an object from the model to get ID.

```
 $mealplaninput = new MealPlanInput;
    $mealplaninput->meal_type = $meal;
    $mealplaninput->suitable_for = $suited;
    $mealplaninput->allergens = $allerg;
    $mealplaninput->specific_allergen = $spec;
    $mealplaninput->no_of_people = $nop;
    $mealplaninput->start_date = $request->date;
    $mealplaninput->no_of_days = $nod;
    $mealplaninput->user_id = $currentuserid;
    $mealplaninput->save();  
    
    $uniquemealplanid = $mealplaninput->id;
```

Comment: When posting an answer, please add an explanation as well, like why they should do it like this instead of their current attempt (why that didn't work and so on).

Comment: According to [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), the `::create()` method should return the newly created model though: _"Alternatively, you may use the create method to "save" a new model using a single PHP statement. The inserted model instance will be returned to you by the create method"_.

Answer (score 1):

you need to try

```
$uniquemealplanid = $mealplaninput->id;
```

insted of

$uniquemealplanid = $mealplaninput->id();